# How do you create a string with a single format with a variable that may hold different values in python?

Tags: python, string, variables, string-formatting

I'm trying to do something along the lines of this:

```
string = "this is my %s string" % (foo)
list = ["first", "second", "g", "last"]     
for entry in list:
    foo = entry
    print(string)
```

Though it seems foo needs to be declared before string, and the string is evaluated before my for loop. Is there something more Pythonic I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fmt_str ='out {}'

for val in ["a", "b", 1]:
    print fmt_str.format(val)
```

prints:

```
out a
out b
out 1
```

You need to do the formatting of the string *inside* of your loop.  When you format the string (using either the old `%` or new style `format`) it returns the result, not a function that binds over `foo`.

[new style docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings)

Comment: Is this answer essentially the same as alecxe's, only with the new style format?

Comment: @joshua.thomas.bird Yes.  You should use the new style when possible, they claim the old style will be deprecated eventually, maybe, after they get it out of the standard library.

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

```
string = "this is my %s string"
l = ["first", "second", "g", "last"]     
for entry in l:
    print(string % entry)
```

prints:

```
this is my first string
this is my second string
this is my g string
this is my last string
```

Note that calling a variable `list` is a bad practice since it shadows built-in.